# Apache Beam - Batching elements for API calls with the Go SDK?

Tags: go, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm building a Beam pipeline with the Go SDK.

I have to do some data enrichment by calling a ML model somewhere on the Cloud.

As I am processing a lot of elements, I can't just make an API call for each element, this will introduce a huge latency. I need to send a batch of elements.

I know in python there is a `BatchElements()` PTransform, how to make something similar in Go?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such transform that is part of the Beam Go SDK at this time.

You would need to translate the GroupIntoBatches [[1](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/GroupIntoBatches.java), [2](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/d8c11464e9af426448c057993e3dca51adb8d697/sdks/python/apache_beam/transforms/util.py#L684)] implementation into Go code. This would be a valuable contribution to Apache Beam so please contribute it if you do this.

Comment: thanks, this is a must have feature I'll probably dive into it

Comment: That would be great, and you may find the Apache Beam contribution guide a helpful starting place on how to contribute your change (https://beam.apache.org/contribute/)